# FileSystemWatcher vs. MSMQ. What to choose?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, filesystemwatcher

I have a server that soon will start receiving files. The files will be placed in a folder. I have to read the files and save the data to my db on at a time. Could I just use FileSystemWatcher to keep an eye on the folder, and then process the files as the watcher finds a new file? Or should I also make use of MSMQ so the files will be placed on a queue after the watcher finds a new file? Is it overkill to use MSMQ? MSMQ is a nice thing to have but as long as the watcher only takes care of one file at a time, then I'm not too sure if its really necessary to use MSMQ. Would the FileSystemWatcher be enough to ensure that only one file is being processed at a time? If the process of the file fails, the file will still be in the folder so it wont be lost.
So basically I have to choose between these two models:

Incoming file -> File is placed in folder -> Watcher sees the file -> Code behind watcher reads the file and saves it to db -> Watcher returns to folder to wait for new file.

or

Incoming file -> File is placed in folder -> Watcher sees the file -> Watcher puts a message(contains the path to the file) on a queue and returns to watching the folder -> A QueueWatcher sees the message, reads the file from the path and saves the data in the DB -> QueueWatcher reruns to listen to the queue for new messages.

Comment: unless you're in the need of handling disconnected system I would keep things simple

Comment: `Msmq is a nice thing to have` What does it give you in this situation that you actually need?

Comment: Thats my question :) I started out thinking that I would need msmq because I was told our server needed to handle a lot of incomming files. Now I know that the files will be sent to us by being placed in a folder on our server. Then I turned to filesystemwatcher but before making the decision final, i just wanted to make sure its a sufficient solution :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is whether your system is going to receive lots of files in a short time period. As stated in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx):

> "If there are many changes in a short time, the buffer can overflow.
>   This causes the component to lose track of changes in the directory,
>   and it will only provide blanket notification. Increasing the size of
>   the buffer with the InternalBufferSize property is expensive, as it
>   comes from non-paged memory that cannot be swapped out to disk, so
>   keep the buffer as small yet large enough to not miss any file change
>   events."

So if this will be the case you might want to use a different approach, say just poll with a service and keep a record of processed files.

Comment: That is a solved problem. Just ensure that you don't do any real work in the event handler. Just put the eventargs in a queue and have a worker thread doing the work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `FileSystemWatcher` only. If that's insufficient then you can extend your solution. Occam's razor still stands.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, MSMQ is more complex, hard to develop and hard to maintain technology then for example windows service written in C# which uses a FileSystemWatcher.

But I prefer another way: notify the file server by touching a web service notifying that the new file has arrived.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to solve. After using the FileSystemWatcher I changed it so that the file writing part of the system notifies the other side with an explicit message sent over a TCP socket that a new file is ready.

I don't know whether you can change this side of the transfer so it may not be a solution to your problem.